# How to export python list into the excel sheet

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, sqlite, django-forms

List item

I will append to many data into the list like the

```
def export_excel()
    all = []
    all2 = []
        if set==''
            data = all_dataset()
            data.serialnumber = serialNumber
            data.name = name
            date.dob = dob
            data.save()
            all.append(data)
        else
            data = all_dataset()
            data.serialnumber = serialNumber
            data.name = name
            date.dob = dob
            data.save()
            all2.append(data)
```

now i want to export these all information into the excel worksheets and download these excel sheet by anchor tags.

how could i do this
please help me out..

it will show like this:

```
Serial no   name    dob
1           pk     12/08/18
2           gk     15/07/18
```

[update]
i try this code:

```
d = pd.DataFrame(all)
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('data.xlsx') 
    d.write_row(row,col,model) 
    writer.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write list to excel sheet then use [xlsxwriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#write_column).

```
worksheet.write_column('col1', all)
```

Comment: i need all column not a single one...and also wanted to download that sheet

Comment: @pawassingh can you please post contents of your list ?

Comment: what content do u want? I explain everything.

Comment: I want sample list `all`

Comment: all = [] is append all item that will shown in the question that i asked.

Comment: What will be the contents of both the list at last ?

Comment: now see, is set==' ' that mean if no item in the database the item is inserted into the data base and if some item is already in the database then it show that "item is already in the database" now i want both data will show in the excel sheet where we check which is inserted which will not.